# Round a SQL column up or down depending on value and adding a custom string format at the end

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sample database table that has 2 columns, Name and Balance. How can I round the entire column up or down depending on its value and adding a custom string at the end. For example
If I have a Balance of 15,000.00 how can I round it to show 15k and for Name B balance would be 25k. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk5Xo.png) how can I change it to look like this table [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMKUR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

```
Declare @YourTable table (Name varchar(50),Balance money)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('A',15000)
,('B',25360)
,('C',1255555)
,('D',945)

Select *
      ,Formated =coalesce( 
                          left(nullIf( convert(int,Balance) / 1000000000 ,0),3)+'B'
                         ,left(nullIf( convert(int,Balance) / 1000000 ,0),3)+'M'
                         ,left(nullIf( convert(int,Balance) / 1000 ,0),3)+'K'
                         ,left(nullIf( convert(int,Balance) / 100 ,0),3)  -- Not sure why 9 and not 945
                         )
 From  @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
Name    Balance     Formated
A       15000.00    15K
B       25360.00    25K
C       1255555.00  1M
D       945.00      9   -- Not clear why this would not be 945
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arithmetic and string operations:

```
select concat( floor(balance / 1000), 'K')
```

You could make this conditional as well:

```
select (case when balance < 1000 then cast(balance as varchar(255))
             when balance < 1000000 then concat( floor(balance / 1000), 'K')
             else concat( floor(balance / 1000000), 'M')
        end)
```